# How to view/manage sharepoint site group email address?

Tags: office-365, site-mailboxes

I'm trying to help a friend setup Office365 for a small business for which she is the office admin. Previously they have just used a generic pop email service, but wanted to upgrade to something a bit more advanced, for file and calendar sharing etc.

I'm getting very confused about the best way to manage shared document storage, and generic office email addresses etc.

Previously they have just used individual email addresses like, office@[companyname].com, sales@[companyname].com etc. This has been a hassle when a new person takes over, as the previous employees details are associated directly with that address.

I was thinking that for Office 365, it would be a better idea to create individual email addresses for each employee (i.e. sally.sue@[companyname].com), and then use a shared mailbox (even though it might only have one member), for each generic email address.

My reasoning is that if an employee leaves, the tech support person can simply assign a new person to that shared mailbox.

This is where it brings me to sharepoint.

I was trying to setup the shared document storage by first creating a sharepoint site. When I create a sharepoint site, it automatically creates the group email address to match.

So far so good. However, after creating the site, I cannot find this group email address listed anywhere.

While trying to search for how to find and manage this address, I found this link...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-site-mailbox-to-collaborate-and-coordinate-team-email-57e361eb-39ef-400e-92de-f6408dab6b2b

> Important: The site mailbox feature in SharePoint is being deprecated beginning in March, 2017. This feature will be removed entirely in a future release.

Is the "site mailbox feature" the same as the site group email address? If so, obviously I don't want to be setting up a brand new Office365 setup using deprecated features.

If the sharepoint site "shared mailbox" is not the correct way to do what I want to do, what is the correct way? If the "shared mailbox" is the correct way to do it, how do I find and manage this email address in the Sharepoint site manager?

Finally, is it even a recommended approach to use shared email addresses in this cases, versus simply creating "Sally Sue's" email as "office@[companyname].com" rather than "sally.sue@[companyname].com?

I hope I'm posting this in the correct place. I think my particular problem is with Sharepoint, but perhaps it's just a noob Office365 question, if so it would be greatly appreciated if someone could point me to the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found it.

I can view and manage the site "Group Email" by going to "Groups" -> "Active Groups" within the Microsoft 365 admin center.